# Cryptocurrency hourly historical prices

Tags: data-request, prices, download

I have found a variety of resources that provide daily historical prices for cryptocurrencies. However, I can hardly find any places where I can download hourly historical prices. Can anyone point me to a good place? More specifically, I want to download or web-scrape the historical hourly prices of Sashimi and Ethereum.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about hourly data, but I've never seen that available for free. It's generally the basis of paid service plans.

Coinecko has documentation on how to [download their data](https://support.coingecko.com/hc/en-us/articles/4538748734233-How-can-I-download-CoinGecko-data-in-CSV-Excel-Format-) with daily snapshots as you noticed.

Their link for [Sashimi](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/sashimi/historical_data#panel) and [Ethereum](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/ethereum/historical_data#panel)

If you start recording the data hourly on your PC, you can archive every hour going forward. Here is a [description of how to do so](https://towardsdatascience.com/obtain-unlimited-historical-crypto-data-through-simple-api-calls-without-keys-8a6f5ed55b43).